# Basic help on how to use following methods to create a Blackjack game?

Tags: java, loops, object

Wrote the code for a Deck and Card class which you can find below but I am unsure how to use these to help me create a working Blackjack game.

I am *certainly* not asking for you to do the work for me nor tell me all the answers, just to give me a basic idea of how you would program this game using basic beginner Java programming.

```
//Represent a playing card
public class Card
{
    //Instance variables:
    int suit; //0=clubs, 1=diamonds, 2=hearts, 3=spades
    int rank; //1=ace, 2=2,..., 10=10, 11=J, 12=Q, 13=K

    //Constructor:
    public Card (int theSuit, int theRank)
    {
        suit = theSuit;
        rank = theRank;
    }

    //Print the card in a human-readable form:
    public void printCard()
    {
        String[] suits = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};
        String[] ranks = {"narf", "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
            "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
        System.out.println(ranks[rank] + " of " + suits[suit]);
    }
}


//Represents a standard deck of 52 variables
public class Deck
{
    //Instance variable:
    Card[] cards;

    //Constructor
    public Deck()
    {
        cards = new Card[52];

        int index = 0; //Use to assign to the correct index of cards
        for (int suit = 0; suit <= 3; suit++)
        {
            for (int rank = 1; rank <= 13; rank++)
            {
                cards[index] = new Card(suit, rank);
                index++;
            }
        }
    }

    public void printDeck()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++)
          cards[i].printCard();
    }

    public void shuffle()
    {
        int randomIndex;
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
        {
            randomIndex = (int)(Math.random() * 52);
            swapCards (i, randomIndex);
        }
    }

    public void swapCards(int index1, int index2)
    {
        Card temp = cards[index1];
        cards[index1] = cards[index2];
        cards[index2] = temp;
    }
}
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This site <s>(http://jcode.tripod.com/Games.html)</s> has java source code for various card games. Studying and understanding them may help you in your quest.

/Edit
Link broken. Java source for a blackjack game can be found here http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=3562&lngWId=2

Comment: Unable to make an account, would you mind just linking the source code?